# 500 Internal Server Error: Python Bottle API

Tags: python, api, url, url-routing, bottle

I am developing a simple API using Python - Bottle.

This is how I am using routing for enabling API HTTP request:

```
@route('/expand')
def expand(url = ""):
    url = request.query.get('url', '')
    if url == "":
        return {"success" : False,
            "start_url" : url,
            "final_url" : "",
            "url_list" : []
            }
    url_list = expandURL(url)
    return {"success" : True,
            "start_url" : url,
            "final_url" : url_list[-1],
            "url_list" : url_list
            }
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
2014-09-24 18:50:24,930 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-09-24 18:50:24,933 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 764, in _handle
2014-09-24 18:50:24,933 :    return route.call(**args)
2014-09-24 18:50:24,933 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1575, in wrapper
2014-09-24 18:50:24,933 :    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
2014-09-24 18:50:24,933 :  File "/home/sahildua2305/mysite/bottle_app.py", line 41, in expand
2014-09-24 18:50:24,933 :    url_list = expandURL(url)
2014-09-24 18:50:24,933 :  File "/home/sahildua2305/mysite/bottle_app.py", line 9, in expandURL
2014-09-24 18:50:24,933 :    return unshorten_me(url, urls)
2014-09-24 18:50:24,933 :  File "/home/sahildua2305/mysite/bottle_app.py", line 14, in unshorten_me
2014-09-24 18:50:24,933 :    h.request('HEAD', parsed.path)
2014-09-24 18:50:24,933 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
2014-09-24 18:50:24,933 :    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :    self.endheaders(body)
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :    self._send_output(message_body)
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :    self.send(msg)
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :    self.connect()
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :    self.timeout, self.source_address)
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :    raise err
2014-09-24 18:50:24,934 :error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

This how I am testing the calls by sending `params={'url':'http://tuq.in/sahil'}` to the link [https://sahildua2305.pythonanywhere.com/expand] which gives 500 Internal error. Sending same request without any parameter gives no error!

Please help me in rectifying the errors..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a free account and they do not permit internet access to anything except whitelisted sites.

The reason you only get the error when you provide a parameter is that the code that makes the request (in expandURL) is only called when there's a parameter.

Comment: They don't even provide internet access to their own hosted applications?
like - sahildua2305.pythonanywhere.com ?

Comment: The URL you're trying to access in your code is http://tuq.in/sahil, which is not whitelisted.

Comment: That implies that I can never host my API on PythonAnywhere? That's bad!

Comment: It implies that you can't host your API on a free PythonAnywhere account.